# cakephp set class with checkboxes

Tags: cakephp, xpath

I have an array that looks like:

```
Array (
    [63] => 0
    [64] => 1
    [65] => 1
    [66] => 0 )
```

Is there a way to extract the keys for all the values that are equal to 1 (in this case I just want 64 and 65) using Set::extract or Set::remove or some other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way may be like this:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach($your_array as $value)
{
  if ($value == 1)
  {
    $new_array[] = $value;
  }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Or you can use the [array_filter](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_array_filter.asp) function.

Comment: I am aware of using foreach and am currently doing something similar to this, but I was just wondering if it is possible with the Set class

Comment: Yes you can use the array_filter function too.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use the Set class?  array_filter is (probably) going to be the fastest.

Comment: I just thought using the Set class would be cleaner. I haven't used array_filter before but it looks like if you pass it without a callback argument, it will remove the ones that are 0 because they are equal to false. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Jason: that is great news then :)

Answer (score 1):

Sarfrarz is right.. array_filter will be the most efficient solution.

but if you still want to use cakphp's builtin method then you should look at the manual for such things.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/640/Set